# While submitting a form I check if there the e-mail isnt already in the sql database but it doesnt work

Tags: php, sql, database, for-loop

I'm using a fetchAll and a for loop to do the trick. In the if statement with $validate as result I tried numbers, boolean and now strings to get the result. Nothing worked so far. Here is my code:

```
$groep_naam = $_POST['groep'];
$naam = $_POST['naam'];
$adres = $_POST['adres'];
$mail2 = $_POST['mail2'];
$pass1 = md5($_POST['pass1']);
$pass2 = md5($_POST['pass2']);

$select = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM deelnemers");
$select->execute();
$result = $select->fetchAll();
$len = count($result);
for ($x=0;$x<$len;$x++) {
    $mail1 = $_POST['mail1'];
    $db_mail = $result[$x][mail];
    if ($db_mail != $mail1) {
        $validate = "true";
    }
    if ($db_mail == $mail1) {
        $validate = "false";
    }
}

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if ($mail1 == $mail2 && $pass1 == $pass2) {
        if ($validate == "true") {
            $add = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO deelnemers (groep_naam, naam, adres, mail, pass, rechten) VALUES ('$groep_naam', '$naam', '$adres', '$mail1', '$pass1', 'user')");
            $add->execute();
        } if ($validate == "false") {
            echo '
                <script>
                    $("#duplicateEntry").modal("show");
                </script>
            ';
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. Instead of fetching *all* emails, you should do a query to check if that particular email exists in db.

Pseudocode:

```
$select = $db->prepare("SELECT 1 FROM deelnemers WHERE mail = :email");
$select->bindValue(':email', $_POST['mail1']);
$select->execute();
$validate = $select->rowCount() > 0; //rowCount/rowExists/whatever to check if the query returned anything
```

Looking at your current code, probable mistake is on line

```
$db_mail = $result[$x][mail];
```

It probably should've been

```
$db_mail = $result[$x]['mail'];
```

Another thing, you loop through **all** emails comparing them with the one from request, so even if you find the one email matching it, later in another loop you rewrite your `$validate` value.

Comment: I get the error "Call to undefined method PDOStatement::AddBind()"

Comment: @TheShadowmaster Yeah, I said it's a **pseudocode**, I don't use php much. Looking at the manual, it seems there's a `bindValue()` method. I'll adjust my answer.